# How to check if two values in Lua are primitively equal?

Tags: lua, comparison, lua-api, c-api

When overriding equality operators in Lua (via the "`__eq`" metamethod), is there a way to still check for primitive equality (ie. not calling the overridden `__eq`, but checking if the two table values are referentially the same?)   I need to do this from the C API, but I cannot find a suitable function there.

For example:

```
lua_newtable(L);
lua_newtable(L);
assert(!some_comparison());
lua_pushvalue(L,-1);
assert(some_comparison());
```

Where `some_comparison()` does not invoke the `__eq` metamethod.

(Please note `lua_compare()` does not satisfy this, in particular.  I want a `lua_rawcompare()`, if you will - or rather a trick or workaround that will give me the equivalent.  The idea is to prevent infinite recursion in a `__eq` implementation...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you mean to use [`lua_rawequal`](https://devdocs.io/lua~5.3/index#lua_rawequal):

> ```
> int lua_rawequal (lua_State *L, int index1, int index2);
> ```
>
> Returns 1 if the two values in indices `index1` and `index2` are
>   primitively equal (that is, without calling metamethods). Otherwise
>   returns 0. Also returns 0 if any of the indices are not valid.

Comment: Whoops, yeah.   Scanned through the API twice and somehow missed it both times!